# Leaflet Map Container already initialized

Tags: leaflet, gis, cartodb

I'm creating an application with CartoDB that uses a 'map' object from Leaflet. Every time I run my app, the console runs the error: *Uncaught Error: Map container is already initialized.*

Here is the JS code. I've tried different approaches for hours, but nothing works. I would really appreciate some help here.

```
  $( document ).ready(function(){
        var mymap =  L.map('map_div', {
          zoomControl: true,
          center: [40.4000, -3.7167],
          zoom: 6
        });

        var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
        }).addTo(mymap);
    });
```

//Please note that I have a "map_div"  in my html and css

Thanks!

Comment: This generally means you already initialized the map on the map_div somewhere else, or you might be calling your code twice, I will have to see the context this code is running in

Comment: you could add a console.log('init map'); just before the var mymap = L.map and use your browser console to debug

Comment: Hi Cstruter and FranceImage, 

Thanks for your replies: the full repo is here: https://github.com/jaimecartodb/geomadrid

Also, I've tried to add console.log('init map'); before initializing var mymap and it just says "init map" on the console, but nothing else. 

Any help would be appreciated. 

Thanks, 

Jaime

Comment: You should probably reproduce your issue online / share a live site that exhibits your problem, so that people can directly troubleshoot rather than having to dig through your code.